# How do i use linq to do this?

Tags: linq, list, c#-4.0

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtcols.Rows)
{
    if (!avlcols.Exists(x => x.ColName.ToLower() == row["field_name"].ToString().ToLower()))
    {
        avlcols.Add(new Column() 
            {
                ColName=row["field_name"].ToString(),
                ColWidth=row["field_width"].ToString() 
            });
    }
}
```

Adding only columns that dont exist in avlcols.

Comment: 8 questions, 0 accepted answers? Can you fix that?

Comment: i am new here , how do u do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if statment to

```
!avlcols.Contains(x => x.ColName.ToLower() == row["field_name"].ToString().ToLower()))
```

May I also Suggest using syntax like this instead

```
!avlcols.Contains(x => String.Equals(x.ColName, row["field_name"].ToString(), OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `avlCols.Exists` with `avlCols.Contains` and you're there.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = from row in dtcols.Cast<DataRow>()
           where !avlcols.Exists(x => x.ColName.Equals(row["field_name"].ToString(),StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           select row;
foreach(var row in rows)
{
    avlcols.Add(new Column()
    {
        ColName = row["field_name"].ToString(),
        ColWidth = row["field_width"].ToString()
    });
}
```